# Use a stream as file?

Tags: c#, stream, filestream, naudio, audio-converter

I am working on a **telephony application** using a third party library to send audio across the wire.

This third party library only accepts a very specific wav format, and **takes in the file as a filename path on disk**. Our current audio files are not in this format. I can use `NAudio` to convert from our legacy format to this new format.

However, I don't really want two sets of audio files floating around.

What I basically want to do is take an `NAudio.WaveStream` and be able to pass it to the third party library **without writing it to disk**, because the library takes a path to a filename. If performance is bad, I will be forced to have multiple sets of audio files, but I would like to avoid this. I am not even sure what terms to Google.

**Is this a use case for memory mapped files?**

Comment: I don't see how memory mapped files could help given that the third party library is expecting a string..

Comment: This is why the third party library should be using streams. You don't need two have two sets of files you can manage the temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not worth your while but if you're absolutely stuck with the 3rd party app and are against writing to disk you could create a virtual drive using a library like http://dokan-dev.net/en/.  You could intercept the requests from the 3rd party app and stream the converted  files to it as they were needed.

Saying that, I would probably take the hit on writing the files to a normal drive.

If nothing else it'll kick off your searches.